# How can I get the timestamp of deploying and loading process of a portlet in liferay 6?

Tags: java, liferay, tomcat7, liferay-6, portlet

My scenario is the next one, I want to get the current state of the portlets availables  in the  liferay portal, but the main idea is to generate a chart or some graphic resource and fill it with the information of the exact timestamp when the portlet started to being deployed and the timestamp when the portlet is fully loaded into the portal, right now I don't know how can I get these timestamps, I tried to read it from the catalina.out but for my project leader is not correct to do that. thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, create a HotDeployListener or listen to messagebus HOT_DEPLOY messages

#### Option 1: HotDeployListener

When a portlet or any other plugin is deployed, Liferay executes a list of HotDeployListener listeners that are defined in `hot.deploy.listeners` property of portal.properties

See default value in [Hot Deploy section of portal.properties](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Hot%20Deploy)

The hot deploy listener receives a `HotDeployEvent` object that contains information about portlet is being deployed, [for example servletcontext can be retrieved](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/deploy/hot/PortletHotDeployListener.java#L316-L325)

You have to implement your own `HotDeployListener`, [see javadoc documentation](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/deploy/hot/HotDeployListener.html) and add it your portal-ext.properties.

You have to copy the default value of `hot.deploy.listeners` property to your portal-ext.properties and add to that list yours listener.

For more information see documentation in portal.properties file:

> Input a list of comma delimited class names that implement com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployListener. These classes are used to process the deployment and undeployment of WARs at runtime.
>
> The listeners are invoked in the order defined by this property. PluginPackageHotDeployListener must always be invoked first. SpringHotDeployListener must always be invoked before ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener. MessagingHotDeployListener must always be invoked last.

#### Option 2: listen to messagebus HOT_DEPLOY messages

After portlet is deployed, a HOT_DEPLOY message is sent to Liferay message bus by the MessagingHotDeployListener, see: [portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/deploy/hot/MessagingHotDeployListener.java#L70-L75](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/deploy/hot/MessagingHotDeployListener.java#L70-L75)

You can listen to that event creating a listener and call to `MessageBusUtil.registerMessageListener(DestinationNames.HOT_DEPLOY, myListener)` or `MessageBusUtil.registerMessageListener("liferay/hot_deploy", myListener)`.

The listener must implement `MessageListener`interface, [see javadoc documentation](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/messaging/MessageListener.html)

For more information about Liferay messagebus see following links:

- https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/liferays-message-bus-system
- http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/11/lifeay-message-bus-portlethandling-bulk.html
- https://web.liferay.com/es/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Message+Bus